# Is the Radeon HD 7650 compatible with ubuntu?

Tags: ati, radeon

I am planning to buy a new notebook. I found a cheap one with Radeon HD 7650M . Will it be fully supported by Ubuntu? I had problems with my previous ATI card (xpress 1250) and I do not want to have the same problems again.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeedy.
One way to help confirm this and help with your decision making is go to [launchpad bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux?field.searchtext=%20Radeon%20HD7650M&search=Search&field.status%3alist=NEW&field.status%3alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status%3alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package=) and search for your hardware.  One bug for this particular piece of hardware indicates almost 100% compatibility.
To be fair though doing the same for xpress 1250 confirms a lot more bugs and a lot more people being affected. Which all goes to confirm HD 7650M is a good choice.

Might be worth doing the same for your notebook model before committing!?

Observing the flame count indicates how many people have marked themselves as affected so this also is indicative of how compatible your hardware is with Ubuntu when searching.
Try updating to the latest release of Ubuntu to increase the chance of success without having to go hunting a suitable kernel for your hardware that is being used.
Problems do come and go due to updates but these get fixed or you can load an older kernel where hardware compatibility is known to be good.
I used to use nvidia but after using ATI will not look back!

It might be worth reminding you most things that are cheap are cheap for a reason!

Answer (score 0):

also check your Notebook here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work just fine for you, however, I do not see it on the [Radeon Drivers supported cards list here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver)